# Implementing filters in django for e-commerce website

Tags: django, search, e-commerce

I am implementing an e-commerce website using django. The product catalog will be big (hundreds of products). I would like to know how I should implement product filters in search.

E.g. let's say I put up about 30 products initially. The user might want to filter the search based on some product attributes like color, size, category, etc.

Is there any feature in django that enables building such features? If not, how should I go about it? Is querying the database everytime the user picks an attribute, the only approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [faceted search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search).

[Haystack](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html) should be the django app you are looking for.

Furthermore you could take a look at [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter)